# FIX Protocol : 35=8 Execution Report coming in log file but not passing through fromApp()/onMessage()

Tags: python, quickfix, fix-protocol

I am sending the below FIX sample message using the quickfix python library.

```
8=FIX4.4,9=225,35=D,34=3,49=AB,52=20220919-07:43:13.917,56=CD,11=44536,15=EUR,17=00002,21=3,37=44536,38=918293,40=2,44=0,48=11,54=1,55=EURUSD,58=LKLA,
59=0,60=20220919-07:43:13.917,64=20220921,78=1,79=LKLA,80=918293,448=f88f2f6277,10=097
```

Immediately after sending the message, I am getting the message back from the server with 35=8 tag. Please see the below the message

```
8=FIX4.4,9=201,35=8,49=CD,56=AB,34=2,52=20220919-07:56:05.330,11=44536,15=EUR,38=918293,40=2,54=1,55=EURUSD,59=0,64=20220921,
6=0.,14=0,17=5249952-1024823399,31=0.,32=0,37=5249952-1024823399,39=0,150=0,151=918293,10=047
(tags 35=Execution report, 39= New, 150 = New)
```

When the trade is executed in FXALL, and when I send new FIX messages again, All the executed trades are logged in messages.current.log file. I am getting the below message in log file but not in fromApp.

```
8=FIX4.4,9=520,35=8,49=CD,56=AB,34=3,52=20220919-11:24:03.145,39=2,37=152648401_0_0,11=44536,17=152648401_0_0,150=F,1=test@bc,64=20220921,55=EUR/USD,40=1,15=EUR,31=0.9997,194=0.9997,195=0.,151=0,6=0.9997,75=20220919,119=918017.51,120=USD,78=1,79=LKLA ,80=918293,1908=1,1909=5493004U2OZSNMN2ML88852648401L0A0,1911=1,60=20220919-11:12:47,453=2,448=test@bc,447=C,452=11,448=BANK2,447=B,452=1,6977=1,6978=BANK2,6979=0.99965,
6980=0.00,6981=0.99965,6982=0.9997,6983=0.00,6984=0.9997,54=1,14=918293,38=918293,32=918293,7055=44536_0_0,10=124,
(tags 35=Execution report, 39=Filled, 150=Filled)
```

How do i get the above message(35=8 filled) in Onmessage/fromApp.

Is there any way/message that i can send to get all the executed trades till now?
something like:

```
8=FIX.4.4|9=158|35=8|34=3|49=AB|52=20220912-09:55:25.467|56=CD|6=0|11=44536|14=986604|17=00002|31=0|32=986604|37=00001|38=986604|39=2|54=1|55=EURUSD|58=44536|150=2|151=0|10=18
```

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking. Do you want to parse the incoming `ExecutionReport` message within your `fromApp` implementation, or just log the message to the screen? Also, it would be helpful to see the code you have written so far - particularly the implementation of `fromApp` and the relevant overloaded version of `onMessage`.

Answer (score 0):

The reasons I know are:

- Your lib might be ignoring PossDupFlag(43=Y) messages (IgnorePossDupResendRequests=Y configured if you are using QuickfixN - http://quickfixn.org/tutorial/configuration.html)
- Your system is rejecting the messages that don't match against the DataDictionary used by the other counter party

Please check if your app is sending Reject messages (35=3) to the counter party immediately after receiving an ExecutionReport (35=8). If so, it will indicate that you might have some issues at your DataDictionary file. In this case your app will reject the messages and the ExecutionReport (35=8) will not be captured by your fromApp method.

My suggestion is:

- check if you are sending 35=3 to the counter party. If it is true, check the 35=3 information, you will notice the reason the message was rejected
- double check your data dictionary against the counter party's dictionary
- double check if your session configuration file contains the entries below (considering quickfixJ)

```
ValidateFieldsOutOfOrder=N
ValidateFieldsHaveValues=N
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateUnorderedGroupFields=N
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
```